# htaccess DirectoryIndex and capturing url parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Need some quick help with url rewriting.

Currently using the following in an htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php?Screen=Home&Category=1
```

If we hit `www.website.com` it loads -> `/index.php?Screen=Home&Category=1` and we don't show the ugly url.

We are wanting to capture url parameters however but they are being sent to a 404.  So if you navigate to `www.website.com/?param=1` it doesn't work.  We are not capturing the url parameter and appending it to the directory index string.

So we want `www.website.com/?param=1` to hit `/index.php?Screen=Home&Category=1&param=1`

We tried to use:

```
RewriteRule ^/\?(.*)$ /index.php?Screen=Home&Category=1&%1 [L]
```

But had no luck...

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule` expression. But using the `QSA` flag essentially does what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?Screen=Home&Category=1 [L,QSA]
```